# Is it possible to know which Columns are taking more disk space in a table?

Tags: mysql, database-size

I have a huge table with 3 million records and the table size is 900 MB approximately.

I want to know which column I can delete to save more space. I want to know the disk space each column is taking in the table.

I want to calculate the disk usage with its data for example `columnA` is using total 250MB and `columnB` is using 30 MB. I just want to know how much space `city` column and its data is taking in the full table. If that is too much I can delete that column. Some cities' names are really long some smaller.

Can you please write the query? My table name is `asins` and column is `city` for example.

I must delete the columns which are taking huge space. My task is to reduce DB size by figuring out which columns are heavy and then deleting those columns completely.

Comment: Why would you even delete column based on size, don't you want to check with your application design first?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(LEN(city)) AS [varchar LEN] , SUM(DATALENGTH(city)) AS [varchar DATALENGTH] from dbo.asins`

Comment: error in the query near '[varchar LEN] , SUM(DATALENGTH(city)) AS [varchar DATALENGTH] from dbo.asins'

Comment: Sorry works for SQLserver. you might need to tweak for mysql.

Comment: By your logic, if the table has a GUID ID column on it, you should delete that. Deleting columns can lead to errors in the application, and can lose critical data. For instance, if you print mailing labels out of `asins` then deleting the `city` column would be likely to cause errors, and potentially unmailable letters.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:  `INT` takes 4 bytes; `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes; `DECIMAL(m,n)` takes *approx* m/2 bytes.

`CHAR(n)` takes n bytes if `CHARACTER SET ascii` or `latin1`.  For `utf8`, 3*n, for `utf8mb4`, 4*n.

`VARCHAR(n)`, on the other hand, takes an average of `2+AVG(LENGTH(col))` bytes per row.  Ditto for `TEXT` and `BLOB`.

But... There is overhead.  For example, your 900MB for 3M rows sounds like 300 bytes per row.  However, the arithmetic above may come back with something like 100.  Plan on 2x-3x overhead for InnoDB tables, including indexes.

In checking a list of 3.2M cities, I found the max to be 91 bytes and the average to be 9.8.  (Add to that a 2-byte length.)

If you have 900M people or businesses scattered among a few million cities, it would probably be better to 'normalize' city+country:

```
CREATE TABLE Cities (
    city_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,  -- in case 91 is not enuf
    country_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHARACTER SET ascii, -- 2 bytes; use standard
    PRIMARY KEY (city_id),
    INDEX(city, country_code)  -- guessing that this is useful
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And then replace your city+country in the table with a mere 3-byte `city_id`.  No data lost, and maybe 20MB saved.

If you need to discuss this further, we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE asins`. And, please do the AVG computations.

Also, we should discuss the indexes you do have and/or need.  This can also impact the disk footprint.